# Exclude Sundays from SwiftUI DatePicker

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am creating a reservation function for a business which do not operate on Sundays. I would like **to block all the Sundays from the current day until the next year at the same day as the range**.
I could not find a way to remove elements from a ClosedRange object I have created. So I quickly made a function that would add to an array all the days I want (that means all the days without Sundays).

But now **I cannot find a way to convert my array to a closedRange** (Since the DatePicker **in argument** only accepts a ClosedRange Object. I searched for a way to provide my array as the **in argument** for the DatePicker but it does not work either.

**How can I create this DatePicker that excludes Sundays in SwiftUI?**

Here is the code I wrote to create my [Date] Array :

```swift
let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: monthDebut, duration: monthInSeconds)

let monthInSeconds = TimeInterval(86400*31)

let range:ClosedRange<Date> = dateInterval.start...dateInterval.end

let calendar = Calendar.current

for date in stride(from: dateInterval.start, to: dateInterval.end, by: dayInSeconds) {
    
    if !Date.isSunday(dateToCheck: date) {
        print(calendar.component(Calendar.Component.weekday, from: date), terminator: ", ")
        print(date)
        dateRange.append(date)
        
    }

}
```

Here is my original DatePicker implementation

```swift
DatePicker(
                "Pick a date",
                selection: $reservationDate,
                in:range ?? Date()...Date().addingTimeInterval(86400*365),
                displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .frame(width: 300, alignment: .center)
```

Thanks for the future help!

Comment: I think you will need to make your own component for this.

Comment: Do you have any ressources that i can read to know how to create one ?

Comment: No not really but you could try a view with two pickers, one for the month and one for day where you could adjust the content of the day picker as you want.